# how to remove the duplicated element in the table JSP JAVA array

Tags: java, arrays, jsp

I have two arrays:

```
<%String TXTfileArray[] = (String[])request.getAttribute("txt");%>    
<%String TXTContentArray[] = (String[])request.getAttribute("content");%>
```

the data in the array is repeated. 
by using the following statement in JSP i can output the array in the table:

```
 <table border="1">
   <tr>
    <th>txt name</th>
    <th>txt content</th>
  </tr>
  <% for (int i=0; i< TXTfileArray.length;i++){ %>

  <tr>
    <td>  <%=TXTfileArray[i] %>  </td>    
    <td> <%=TXTContentArray[i] %>  </td>   <%} %> 
   </tr>
   </table>
```

how to remove the repeated element in the table?

Please do not hard code, as the array is not fixed. the array is depended on the other process.

[image]

Comment: Why you could not use a List?

Comment: Stop using scriptlets. Don't use two arrays of strings, but instead a single LinkedHashSet<SomeClass>, where SomeClass has a name and a content, and properly overrides equals() and hashCode().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding each element in a Set, and if it already exists don't add it to the table:

```
<% Set<String> a = new HashSet<>();
   for (int i=0; i< TXTfileArray.length;i++)
     if (a.add(TXTfileArray[i]) { %>

  <tr>
    <td>  <%=TXTfileArray[i] %>  </td>    
    <td> <%=TXTContentArray[i] %>  </td>   <%} %>
```

Although I think JB Nizet's suggestion of using `LinkedHashSet<SomeClass>` is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: @HiPownedBi add `<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>` at the top just after `<html>`.